# How to Limit the String values in java

Tags: java

I am Extracting the month From this String by using Substring.

```
String main="2014-07-30 13:30:00";
String month=main.substring(5, 7);
```

Bt now i wanted to limit the month 
i.e.

```
if(month<0 || month>12)
{
sysout("Wrong Input");
}
```

So what Shoud i Do???

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(month)<0||...`

Comment: Parse the string using a proper date library.

Comment: use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Use a `DateTimeFormatter` and use `parse` to validate your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using java.time

The modern approach is with the java.time classes.

Parse the string as a date-time object, a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) in this particular case. If the parsing fails, you know the input was wrong.

To parse, alter your input to fully comply with the ISO 8601 standard. This means replacing that SPACE in the middle with a `T`. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2014-07-30 13:30:00".replace( " " , "T" );
```

Catch the exception thrown if the input is faulty such as the month number being out of the range of 1-12.

```
try {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
} catch (DateTimeParseException e ) {
    // Handle this error, when we receive faulty input.
    System.out.println( "Wrong input." ); 
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String main="2014-11-30 13:30:00";
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(main);
        if(!main.equals(formatter.format(date)))
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).